# Excel Put Array Value in Range - Transpose Gives Type Mismatch Error

Tags: excel, vba

UPDATE:

### I had two problems that contributed to this error.  First, I had a clash with a SAS add-in that was messing up the copy/paste functionality.  Second, I had a null value in the array that was causing the transposition to fail.   I have handled the null and everything works fine.

I'm trying to assign an array of values to my Excel worksheet.  When I use the TRANSPOSE function I am getting type mismatch errors.  I don't understand why, there are only about 200 "rows" in the set:

```
Worksheets("xyz").Range("A2").Resize(ValidCode, 5).Value = & _ 
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(CodeData)
```

It works fine when I put a static value instead of the transposed array.  I don't understand what's happening to it.  It is type "Variante/Variante(0 to 4, 0 to 205)"

The array needs to be transposed because I had to redim preserve it in a code loop (so the "columns" are rows, etc.)  I guess I could manually transpose it, but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: The `&` character is not necessary.  What `Type` is `ValidCode` and what is its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The & character is not necessary and in fact raises a `1004` error when I try to implement your code.

Otherwise, I cannot replicate the error you describe, this example code works with or without `Transpose` function, although you need to use `Transpose` to achieve the desired results.

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("xyz")
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A2")
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim CodeData() As Variant

ReDim Preserve CodeData(4, 205)   '## Create a dummy array to test this method
For r = 0 To UBound(CodeData, 1)  '## populate the array with random numbers
    For c = 0 To UBound(CodeData, 2)
        CodeData(r, c) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 100)
    Next
Next

'## Drop this array in to the worksheet:
rng.Resize(UBound(CodeData, 2) + 1, UBound(CodeData, 1) + 1).Value = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(CodeData)


End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, it works fine on mine too.  The problem is happening in the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(CodeData)` part.  Can you think of anything in the array itself that could cause this?

Comment: It also pastes the data just fine if I don't transpose (though the rows/columns are of course inverted.)  So weird.  I guess I can just paste, cut, transpose or something.

Comment: Does *my* code work fine on your computer?  Or does it raise the same error?

Comment: Okay the problem isn't in the code, I just realized that the PASTE SPECIAL is completely greyed out anytime I open Excel.  I think something else is going on beyond just this issue.

Comment: Disable all add-ins and see if that Paste Special error persists?

Comment: So weird!  I disabled everything and it will allow COPY+PASTE SPECIAL but not CUT+PASTE SPECIAL.  This isn't normal.... is it?  They just installed some kind of SAS add-in that (even though disabled) might have broken something.  Thanks for the help, I'll see if I can figure it out.